# Ubuntu 22.04 ERROR: Invalid HADOOP_COMMON_HOME while installing Hadoop 3.3.5

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

Trying to install Hadoop in wsl and after iam trying to run `bin/hdfs namenode -format` command, iam getting mentioned error.

This is how my .bashrc looks like:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
export HADOOP_HOME=~/hadoop/hadoop-3.3.5
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
```

As an example how to install, iam using:

https://kontext.tech/article/978/install-hadoop-332-in-wsl-on-windows

Comment: Hadoop 3.3.4+ require Java 11, not 8, by the way

Comment: @OneCricketeer it requires Java 8 only, Hadoop has Java-11 runtime support for this version(not compile time), but the default is still Java-8 https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/branch-3.3.4/BUILDING.txt#L7

Comment: @AyushSaxena Thanks. The question is about running, though, not building

Comment: For running as well the default is Java-8, it is just Java-11 is also supported.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you need to set `HADOOP_COMMON_HOME`, as well.

You can do this in `hadoop-env.sh` file.